# jquery split array with last element of a chunk being first element of the next chunk

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to split an array in jquery so that after splitting, the last element for previous array should be the first element of current array.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
```

If I do `splice` then it will splice exactly same size and next array will be next element. so if I am splicing it into 5 my output should be

```
var firstArr = arr.splice[0,4];
var secondArr = arr.splice[0,4];
var thirdArr = arr.splice[0,4];
var fourthArr = arr.splice[0,4];
var fifthArr = arr.splice[0,4];
```

Right now I am getting

```
[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8]
...
```

What I need is

```
//firstArr = [1,2,3,4];
//secondArr = [4,5,6,7];
//thirdArr = [7,8,9,10];
//fourthArr = [10,11,12,13];
//fifthArr = [13,14,15,16];
```

How to achieve this in jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) array function that is preferable to using a plain javascript solution. Below is an example that generically handles your requirement by:

- taking the number of chunks as the `ceil` of: the length of input array *plus the `floor` number of duplicated entries*, all divided by the size of the output chunk
- uses `slice` such that the last element for previous array is the first element of current array.

```js
// chunking function
function chunk(arr, size) {
  if (size === 0) return [];
  var arrCount = Math.ceil((arr.length + Math.floor(arr.length / size)) / size);
  var chunks = [];
  for (let i=0; i<arrCount; ++i) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i * (size - 1), i * (size - 1) + size));
  }
  return chunks;
}

// tests
console.log(chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16], 4));
console.log(chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16], 7));
console.log(chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3));
console.log(chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 3));
console.log(chunk([1,2,3], 8));
console.log(chunk([], 10));
console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4], 0));
console.log(chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

let slices = []

let start = 0
let end = 3
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    let slice = arr.slice(start,end)
    slice.push(arr[end])
    start += 3
    end += 3
    slices.push(slice)
}
```